# flutter mp4 H.264 μ-Law 2:1, 8000 Hz format android shows well but ios sows black screen

Tags: ios, flutter, video

i used
video_player: ^2.6.1
chewie: ^1.5.0

android shows well but ios show black screen with audio sound

i download the file and when i sow the details it was
1.4MB, video format: H.264, audio format: μ-Law 2:1, 8000 Hz

i tried to download in phone and use FFmpag with '-i ${file.path} -level 3.0 ${newFile.path}'
it works fine. however, keep downloading in phone its not good cuz of memory and time.

is there other way to sow a video?

```
late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  ChewieController? chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeVideoPlayer();
  }

  Future<void> initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    String makeUrl = '$downloadVideoUrl${widget.videoLink}';

    print(makeUrl);

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      makeUrl,
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
        mixWithOthers: true,
      ),
    );
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    await _controller.initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}));
    setState(() {
      chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _controller,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoInitialize: true,
        looping: true,
        placeholder: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
        allowPlaybackSpeedChanging: true,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.black,
            // color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          Center(
            child: chewieController != null &&
                    chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
                ? AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    child: Chewie(controller: chewieController!),
                  )
                : Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Text("Loading", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    ],
                  ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40, horizontal: 8.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```